# Can UUIDField be used as default_auto_field in Django 3.2.^?

Tags: python, django, django-3.2

I have been using UUIDField as my primary key in Django. My project has a hierarchy of models with inherited fields, and at the top, I have the following superclass:

```
import uuid
from django.db import models

class HasIDMixin(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True, name='id')
```

After updating to Django 3.2.4, I get the following warning:

```
WARNINGS:
app_base.MyProject: (models.W042) Auto-created primary key used when not defining a primary key type, by default 'django.db.models.AutoField'.
    HINT: Configure the DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD setting or the AppBaseConfig.default_auto_field attribute to point to a subclass of AutoField, e.g. 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'.
```

Following the advice of the warning, I tried both the DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD in settings.py and the default_auto_field in the app_config and I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Primary key 'django.db.models.UUIDField' referred by DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD must subclass AutoField.
```

I have seen others approach this problem with a custom child class to both UUIDField and AutoField (https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/32577) but no working solution has been posted. Is this currently possible in Django 3.2.^? If not should I find a different primary key solution or roll back?

Comment: The `DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD` will only be used if you don't explicitly specify the primary key field on your model. Just set that setting to a suitable auto field of your choice and keep your `UUIDField` as it is currently in your model.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat this seems to have worked and made the warning go away. Is this a band-aid solution or will Django truly ignore that setting if all my models inherit from the HasIDMixin superclass? If this is a true solution, can you post this as an answer so I can mark it the solution?

Comment: No it is not a bandaid solution, Django will only generate the pk field automatically for your model if it already doesn't have one.

Comment: See this related Django feature request: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/32577

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When one does not set a model field to be the primary key for that model Django will automatically add a field to your model named `id` which will be used as the primary key. This automatically added key is usually `AutoField`. From Django 3.2 onwards Django allows you to set what type of `AutoField` will be used for these automatically generated primary key fields by setting `DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD`.

Considering you explicitly set a primary key for your model Django will not generate a field for it. But still you should specify `DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD` as you might have some model where you don't specify the primary key. You can safely keep your `UUIDField` in your model as it is and also set `DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD` like so:

```
DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.AutoField' # Or one of the other options as per your choice
```

Comment: Thanks for this great Answer.i have 70 tables in my database and now i want to change the id(pk) to BigAutoField  for all tables.can i use `DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'` ? and will the Django User model also change his pk ?

Comment: @amadousow you might have to do a bit more if you have any `ManyToManyField`s with an auto generated through table (In case you don't specify a through table Django creates one), see the note in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field) for this.